# XmlArray deserializes only when ElementName matches class name?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I've encountered something really peculiar, and would love if someone could explain, what is going on here.

Here's code that works perfectly fine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Access")]
    public class Access
    {
        public Access()
        { 
        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Else")]
        public string Else { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Element")]
        public string Element { get; set; }
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "fields")]
        public Field[] Fields { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Field")]
    public class Field
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = @"<Access>
                        <Element>what is this ?!</Element>
                        <Else>432432elseasdas123213</Else>
                        <fields>
                            <Field><Name>Skype</Name><Type>Talking</Type></Field>
                            <Field><Name>IP Phone</Name><Type>Talking</Type></Field>
                            <Field><Name>PC</Name><Type>Still</Type></Field>
                            <Field><Name>Laptop</Name><Type>Mobile</Type></Field>
                        </fields>
                    </Access>";

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Access));

            Access access;

            using (var stream = new StringReader(data))
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                access = (Access)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                Console.WriteLine("Fields");
                foreach (Field item in access.Fields)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Type);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's code ( that is almost enitrely the same ) but does not work as intended:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Access")]
    public class Access
    {
        public Access()
        { 
        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Else")]
        public string Else { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Element")]
        public string Element { get; set; }
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "fields")]
        public Field[] Fields { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "field")]
    public class Field
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = @"<Access>
                        <Element>what is this ?!</Element>
                        <Else>432432elseasdas123213</Else>
                        <fields>
                            <field><Name>Skype</Name><Type>Talking</Type></field>
                            <field><Name>IP Phone</Name><Type>Talking</Type></field>
                            <field><Name>PC</Name><Type>Still</Type></field>
                            <field><Name>Laptop</Name><Type>Mobile</Type></field>
                        </fields>
                    </Access>";

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Access));

            Access access;

            using (var stream = new StringReader(data))
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                access = (Access)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                Console.WriteLine("Fields");
                foreach (Field item in access.Fields)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Type);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference between these 2 pieces of code, is the capitalization on the ElementName on the Field class, and the capitalzation on the elements in the XML, that this class refers to.

1. What the hell ? I just cannot for the world, figure out why would this be the case, does anyone have an explanation ?
2. Does anyone know of a workaround ?

I'd rather not change the capitalization in the XML just to match the ElementName.

Thanks.

Comment: Change the c# code so the ElementName is the same case as tag name.

Comment: The XML comes from an external source, I'd rather not change the capitalization in that XML, if I change the ElementName, and I do not change the tag case, it will not read the element.